# Splitting string using Regex and pattern matching throws an exception

Tags: regex, scala, pattern-matching, scala-2.10

Could you guys please tell me what I'm doing incorrectly trying to extract using regex pattern-matching? I have following code

```
val Pattern = "=".r
val Pattern(key, value) = "key=value"
```

And I get following exception in runtime

```
Exception in thread "main" scala.MatchError: key=value (of class java.lang.String)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's more of a regular expression problem: your regex does not capture any groups, it just matches a single `=` character.

With

```
val Pattern = "([^=]*)=(.*)".r
```

you will get:

```
scala> val Pattern(key, value) = "key=value"
key: String = key
value: String = value
```

**Edit**:

Also, that won't match if the input string is empty. You can change the pattern to make it match, or (better) you can pattern match with the regex, like so:

```
"key=value" match {
   case Pattern(k, v) => // do something 
   case _ => // wrong input, do nothing
}
```

If what you actually wanted was to split the input text with whatever the regex matches, that is also possible using `Regex.split`:

```
scala> val Pattern = "=".r
Pattern: scala.util.matching.Regex = =

scala> val Array(key, value) = Pattern.split("key=value")
key: String = key
value: String = value
```

Comment: Id suggest you add a condition for the pattern to `val Pattern = "([^=]*)=?(.*)".r` just in case an empty string is passed in.

Comment: @korefn you are right, but it feels safer to keep a strict pattern and use pattern matching to do proper error handling.